# Black screen after loging in from GDM to Gnome-shell

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gnome, login

After installing Nvidia drivers either from repository or from Nvidia website, my computer boots normally to GDM login screen. However, when I log in with my user I get for a short period of time a mouse and a background color and, then, a black screen appears that flicker some times. When I login to a newly created user, it works as it should and I am able to enter gnome-shell of this user, but, with my actual user, I can't.

I tried everything from changing grub config file to `nomodeset` or `nvidia-drm.modeset=1` to creating blacklist file to disable nouveau or disable wayland in config file, even tried to install older versions like nvidia-driver-390 and use older kernels, but got the same results.

I had to remove Nvidia driver and re-enable nouveau to be able to use my computer again (in graphical mode).

Does anyone have any idea of what can be done to solve this issue?

I'm using Ubuntu 19.10. I have installed nvidia-driver-395 and nvidia-driver-430 and also tested with installing the latest nvidia-driver-440 from Nvidia website. My nvidia card is GTX 1060 6GB. My main linux kernel is 5.4.0.14

`ls -al ~/.*thority` output:

```
-rw------- 1 thiggy01 thiggy01 58838 jan  5 14:59 /home/thiggy01/.ICEauthority
-rw------- 1 thiggy01 thiggy01     0 jan  7 07:10 /home/thiggy01/.Xauthority
```

thiggy01 is my normal user.

Comment: What make/model Nvidia? What version Ubuntu? What version Nvidia drivers did you try?

Comment: @heynnema I've added what you asked for in my question.

Comment: Did you try Nvidia 440.64? If you CAN work in another user account when Nvidia is installed, but NOT in your normal account, then there's something specific to your account that may be causing the problem. This may take a little work to determine. First, edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.*thority`. Then look in your /home for a Nvidia or .nvidia folder. Also look in .cache for a Nvidia or .nvidia folder.

Comment: @Gryu That's a poor suggestion. What do you expect this user to do with their Documents, Pictures, Videos, etc? Of course config files can cause the problem... what do you think I'm pursuing?

Comment: @heynnema you are right

Comment: Sorry guys. I upgraded my Ubuntu from 19.10 to 20.04 (developer branch) to see if the this issue would be resolved, but now when I install any Nvidia proprietary drive I can't even enter GDM login screen. It only works fully with nouveau.

Comment: @thiggy01 Too bad. I wouldn't have expected 20.04 to fix this, as you've already proven that the problem is specific to your account. See if you can still boot to the 19.10 kernels. Did you look for the folders I requested earlier? Are you ready to do some difficult troubleshooting? Remember to start comments to me with "@heynnema" or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema I managed to install the run file from Nvidia website without dkms and now I can access gdm to login, but I'm still getting a black screen after loging in. I added the command output to my question. And no I have no Nvidia or .nvidia folder in either my home or .cache folder.

Comment: @heynnema I found a .nv folder in my home, but I beleive it is from nouveau because it was there before installing the nvidia driver.

Comment: @thiggy01  If you're still able to login via another user account, I can write you instructions on how to troubleshoot your own account. Are you able to boot to 19.10 still? Report back.

Comment: @heynnema no, I'm using 20.04.

Comment: I can use another account normally

Comment: @thiggy01 Are you able to get to Recovery Mode from GRUB, and/or get to console tty mode with ctrl-alt-f1, and log in using your normal username/password? I have to go out for a couple of hours, and based on your answers, I'll write you a procedure on what to do next, when I return.

Comment: Thank you @heynnema, but I decided to format my partitions and do a fresh install. Now, I just need to restore my backup files.

Comment: @thiggy01 Ok. Hope that gets you operational again.